# setUser does not seem to get set when pulling from database

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am pulling in a user by ID and it seems like in the end it does pull from my database as it logs it all in the console but the state does not update the variables at all. I feel it is something small and stupid keeping me from getting just user 2 to show FirstName LastName - CollectorID | FinanceCompany next to the 2 under the header Update Collector.

[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

  const UpdateUser = () => {
    const { CollectorID } = useParams();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: '',
      CollectorCode: '',
      FinanceCompany: ''
    });

    const { FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode, FinanceCompany } = user;
    
useEffect(() => {
  loadUser();
}, []);// eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

const loadUser = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getCollectors/${CollectorID}`);
  setUser(result.data);
};


console.log(user);
    return (
      <div className="previewWrapper">
        <h1>Update Collectors</h1>
          <div className="wrapper">
            {<div><p>{CollectorID} | {FirstName} {LastName} - {CollectorCode} | {FinanceCompany}</p></div>}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default UpdateUser;
```

Comment: Try using the right-hand side of `loadUser` as the function passed to `useEffect`, and add `CollectorID` as a dependency.

Comment: I have updated the `loadUser()` to now be `loadUser(CollectorID)` but this has no effect on my output as it remains blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect object in your code however your API response is an array of objects. It's clearly visible from your logs.

To verify it you can simple try

```js
setUser(result.data[0]); // instead of setUser(result.data);
```

This line below - always would result `undefined` values.
Since you are assigning an array, your variable destructuring like this would not work

```js
const { FirstName, LastName, CollectorCode, FinanceCompany } = user;
```

.

You might want to change the logic how to store user data since API response and current state does not really match.

Comment: I tried using `setUser(result.data[0]);` and I do get an output that actually showed the user data I wanted when I set the index [0] to the proper one I select so this is one step closer for me. I have just tried doing `setUser(result.data[CollectorID - 1]);` and it works perfectly. Thank you so much for the guidance on this.